# How to make the bar be a button?

Tags: charts, interactive

This is a `BarChart`:

```
BarChart[Tooltip[#, "I want tip"] & /@ {1, 2, 3}, 
 ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle", ChartStyle -> "Pastel"]
```

[image]

I hope when I left-right the bar, then I copy the value into the clipboard. Is it possible?

Comment: how about clicking the bar: `Deploy@BarChart[Button[#, CopyToClipboard[#]] & /@ {1, 2, 3}, 
 ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle", ChartStyle -> "Pastel"]`?

Comment: @kglr I'm sorry I make a little tuning in the origin question. Actually I want the `Button` and `Tooltip` coexsit...

Comment: Tooltip is not removed. If the tooltips are removed in your version/os, you can use `Button[Tooltip@#, CopyToClipboard[#]] &` as wrapper (You might want to add the option `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"`if there are many bars in your chart).

Comment: @kglr Do you mean `BarChart[Button[Tooltip[#, "I want tip"], #] & /@ {1, 2, 3}, 
 ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle", ChartStyle -> "Pastel"]` work for you? My version is 11.2..

Comment: @kglr [The code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/190147/how-to-make-the-bar-be-a-button#comment495374_190147) can draw the bar graphics here, but it cannot copy the value into the clipboard. Please check....

Comment: yode you need to use `BarChart[Button[Tooltip[#, "I want tip"], CopyToClipboard@#] & /@ {1, 2, 3}, ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle", ChartStyle -> "Pastel"]`

Comment: @kglr I'm sorry, [your comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/190147/how-to-make-the-bar-be-a-button#comment495377_190147) is the answer indeed.. Thanks..If you submit it I will accept it..

Comment: ref / BarChart / Scope / Wrappers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can wrap input data with `Button` with action `CopyToClipboard`:

```
data = {1, 2, 3};
BarChart[Button[Tooltip[#, "I want tip"], CopyToClipboard@#] & /@ data, 
  ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle", ChartStyle -> "Pastel"]
```

**Update:** You can add tool tips in several ways:

```
tooltips = {"tooltip1", "tooltip2", "tooltip3"};
```

1. Use `Tooltip` as a wrapper on input data:

```
BarChart[Button[Tooltip@##, CopyToClipboard[#]] & @@@ 
  Transpose[{{1, 2, 3}, tooltips}],
 ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle", ChartStyle -> "Pastel"]
```

2. Use `Placed[tooltips, Tooltip]` as the setting for the option `ChartLabels`:

```
BarChart[Button[#, CopyToClipboard[#]] & /@ data,
 ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle", ChartStyle -> "Pastel",
 ChartLabels -> Placed[tooltips, Tooltip]]
```

3. Use a custom `ChartElementFunction` and pass the tooltips as metadata:

```
ceF[cedf_: "GlassRectangle"] := Button[Tooltip[ChartElementData[cedf][##], #3[[1]]], 
BarChart[Thread[data -> tooltips], ChartElementFunction -> ceF[], 
 ChartStyle -> "Pastel", PlotLabel -> (Paste[])]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is to get a slightly modified version of kglr's comments recorded as an answer. The modification is provide individual tooltips for each bar.

```
BarChart[
  MapThread[
    Button[Tooltip[#1, #2], CopyToClipboard@#1] &,
    {{1, 2, 3}, {"left", "mid", "right"}}], 
 ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle", ChartStyle -> "Pastel"]
```

[image: chart].1

Also, be aware that if only want the tooltip to show the value of the bar, you don't need to specify `Tooltip`; it will be supplied automatically.

```
BarChart[Button[#, CopyToClipboard@#] & /@ {1, 2, 3}, 
  ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle", ChartStyle -> "Pastel"]
```

[image: chart.2]

Comment: Thanks very much..:)